# Does Chinese distinguish in/on/to the south?

Tags: difference

[image]
Does 在伦敦的南面/南边 is a mixture of in/on/to the south of London?

Comment: Feels like a dupe?

Answer (score 1):

Well to distinguish the south-side of London (within) and south of London (outside):

在伦敦的南部/南方/南区/城南 The south-part/side/district/ of London.

Note: 城南 is specifically the south side of a city. 在伦敦的城南。

在伦敦的南边/南面 South of London. Outside of London.

I feel 南边/南面 could be used to mean either inside or outside depending on the context.

Comment: 伦敦以南 = south of London

Comment: So to consolidate the points above, 在伦敦的南部 = South London, while 伦敦以南 = south of London